# What does the first x represent in {x, (x+1), (x-3)}?

Tags: polynomials, graphing-functions, factoring

The question is: "Part of the graph of a polynomial function is shown. Which of the following sets contains only elements that are factors of the polynomial?"

The two answer choices left are B. {(x+1), (x-3)]} and E. {x, (x+1), (x-3)}.
What is the point of the first x in answer choice E.?

[image: Graph]

Answer (score 2):

A polynomials, as you are learning now, can be broken into factors of the form $(x-a)$ where $a$ is a root of the polynomial. A polynomial like $x^3-3x^2+2x$ is has roots at $0$, $1$, and $2$. Therefore, $x^3+3x^2+2x=(x-0)(x-1)(x-2)$, or $x(x-1)(x-2)$. So the $x$ would mean that the polynomial has a root at zero. Yours does not have a root at zero.

Comment: So if an $x$ alone means that the polynomial has a root at zero, then would it have a multiplicity? For example, $y = x(x + 5)^4 (3x - 2)^7$; the two zeroes that I know of are -5 with multiplicity 4, and 2 with multiplicity 7. Would there be another one for $x$?

Comment: No, there are three zeros: -5 with multiplicity 4, 2/3 with multiplicity 7, and 0 with multiplicity 1.